# How can I easily display content of word document in Tkinter window while keeping orginal formating?

Tags: python, tkinter, ms-word, .doc

I have a Tkinter app, which has lengthy manual I already wrote with microsoft word. I want to display that manual (content) in a tkinter window. Word document has `bold` and `italic` formating as well as numbered and bullet lists. Is there way to do this with python standard library? (This is part of a school project witch restrics using downloadable packages.)

The widget can be any scrollable widget (`Text` or multiline `Label`).

Here is text example:

[image]

Comment: `Text` may assign `tag` to selected text and this `tag` may have assigned some formatting values. But it may need to read text char by char and check if it has some formatting and do the same in `Text`. But not all elements can be this way recreated. So finally it is not easy. Tkinter has some external module/widget to display HTML - so you could convert Word to HTML to display - but it doesn't display some CSS values. So it is also not so useful.